# Angular 11 - Role based Auth is not working with other roles (Only the "Operator" is working)

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication

Only the 'operator' can access the page, when the other account with 'super_admin' role it can no longer access the page. I want to restrict the other pages for a certain role.

html:

```
<a mat-list-item
   routerLink="/webinarcrud"
   routerLinkActive="active"
   *ngIf="dataService.roleMatch(['operator']) || dataService.roleMatch(['super_admin'])"
   class="menuNav">
  <mat-icon class="icon">computer</mat-icon>
  Webinars
</a>
<a mat-list-item
   routerLink="/organizationcrud"
   routerLinkActive="active"
   *ngIf="dataService.roleMatch(['super_admin'])"
   class="menuNav">
  <mat-icon class="icon">apartment</mat-icon>
  Organizations
</a>
```

routing-module:

```
{
  path: 'dashboard', 
  component: DashboardComponent, 
  canActivate:[AuthGuardGuard], 
  data:{ roles:['operator']} || {roles:['super_admin'] }
}
```

data-service:

```
public roleMatch(allowedRoles): boolean {
  let isMatch = false;
  const userRoles: any = this.token.getRoles();

  if (userRoles != null && userRoles) {
    for (let i = 0; i < userRoles.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < allowedRoles.length; j++) {
        if (userRoles[i].name === allowedRoles[j]) {
          isMatch = true;
          return isMatch;
        } else {
          return isMatch;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

token-service:

```
public getRoles(){
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("roles"));
}
```

auth-guard:

```
  if (this.token.getToken() !== null) {
    const role = route.data["roles"] as Array<string>;
    const accessToken = route.data.accessToken as string;

    if (role) {
      const match = this.dataService.roleMatch(role);

      if (match) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with this? ```{path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuardGuard], data:{roles:['operator','super_admin']}}```

Comment: Yeah it's also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below changes -

routing-module:

```
{path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuardGuard], data:{roles:['operator','super_admin']}}
```

data-service:

```
public roleMatch(allowedRoles) :boolean{
let isMatch = false;
const userRoles: any = this.token.getRoles();
if(userRoles) {
  for(let i = 0; i<userRoles.length; i++) {
    if(allowedRoles.indexOf(userRoles[i].name) !== -1){
     isMatch = true;
     break;
    }
  }
}
return isMatch;
}
```

Comment: It is not working if the value is -1 then I changed it to 0 it worked but It does not restrict the other role to access the page.

Comment: Could you share output of - localStorage.getItem("roles")

Comment: roles: [{"id":2,"name":"operator","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2021-08-27T09:30:55.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-08-27T09:30:55.000000Z","pivot":{"model_id":1,"role_id":2,"model_type":"App\\Models\\User"}}]

Comment: Are you using name property to get role of the user?

Comment: I updated the code snippet, please check. Vote for it if you find it helpful.